# Java popupmenu in Netbean GUI selectall action

Tags: java, swing, action, jpopupmenu, jtextcomponent

Below is my mouse event code for the clicking action. However this action doesnt work for me. How should i change this to work?

```
  private void menuSelectallMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
  menuSelectall.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction)
  menuSelectall.setText("Select All"); 
  }
```

Comment: *"However this action doesnt work for me*" - What is it suppose to do and what does it currently do?  How is the `menuSelectallMouseClicked` option activated?

Comment: when clicked it should select all in the textarea.

Comment: Okay, so far, it's just setting the text of `menuSelectall` to `Select All`.  Have you tried using [`JTextArea#selectAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll())?

Comment: just tried, doent work.

Comment: Then I two things.  1- Make sure the method is being called and 2- Make sure that the text area you are referencing is the same as the text area on the screen

Comment: i changed my code to   menuSelectall.setAction(textarea.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAction)); 
still doesnt work. both are in the same screen. the click action is in the textarea itself

Comment: Can you provided a runnable example which demonstrates your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a MouseListener to handle events on a popup menu, the menu item should already be created with the specific Action.

You just create a JMenuItem using the Action from the EditorKit and then you add the menu item to your JPopupMenu. The code should be something like:

```
JMenuItem selectAll = new JMenuItem( textarea.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.selectAllAc‌​tion) );
popupMenu.add( selectAll );
```

The menu item will than handle the mouse event and invoke the Action.